# on row double click Image pop ups in a datatable in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am looking to have a Image pop up on row double click in a data table.
The current code I have written displays alert message on double clicking the row. I would like to replace that alert message with a Image. Suggestions to achieve the same.

## Code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(

dashboardPage (
dashboardHeader(title="Report"),
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Table",tabName="Table"))),
dashboardBody(      
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Table",
            DT::dataTableOutput("DataTable")    
    )
  ))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$DataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(iris,rownames=FALSE,selection = 'single',options = list(
  searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = c('copy','excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis'),
  columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))),
  rowCallback = JS(
    "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
    "var full_text = aData[2]",
    # Tooltip for the rows
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
    # Showing a hand as a cursor
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).css('cursor','pointer');",
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).css('font-weight','bold');",
    "}")
  ),
 #On double Click show Alert Message
 callback = JS('
              table.on("dblclick.dt","tr", function() {
              var data=table.row(this).data();
              alert("You clicked on "+data[4]+"\'s row");} 
              )
              ')    )
})
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Used "SweetAlert" instead of Traditional JS Alert Pop ups to add Image on Data Table row click.

## EDIT:

Please download the Sweet Alert plugin JS and CSS file from this link- https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert and place the two files in www folder.    File Location - sweetalert-master\dist

Here is final code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(

dashboardPage (
dashboardHeader(title="Report"),
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Table",tabName="Table"))),
dashboardBody(
  # JS Script and CSS for SweetAlert Plugin
  tags$head(HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='sweetalert.min.js'>   </script>")),
  tags$head(
       tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "sweetalert.css")
    ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Table",
            DT::dataTableOutput("DataTable")    
    )
  ))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$DataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(iris,rownames=FALSE,selection = 'single',options = list(
  searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  buttons = c('copy','excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis'),
  columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))),
  rowCallback = JS(
    "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
    "var full_text = aData[2]",
    # Tooltip for the rows
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
    # Showing a hand as a cursor
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).css('cursor','pointer');",
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).css('font-weight','bold');",
    "}")
 ),
 #On double Click show Alert Message
 callback = JS('
              table.on("dblclick.dt","tr", function() {
              var data=table.row(this).data();
          swal({
          title: "Sweet!",
          text: "Here a custom image.",
          imageUrl: "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/high-resolution-    image/high-resolution-image-2.jpg",
          imageSize: "400x300"
          });
} 
)
  '))
})
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You should mention the required JS and CSS files. Why do you use actually `src='sweetalert.min.js'>` and not `sweetalert2.min.js`? If OP downloads, I guess he loads the latter one.

Comment: @BigDataScientist I have used SweetAlert - https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert , You can either use SweetAlert or SweetAlert2 to achieve the same and accordingly the JS & CSS Script file.

Comment: My point is to edit your post and mention where OP should download the files and that he should store it in the "www" folder etc. -  otherwise your code is not reproducible that easy. For me its ok, i´ve worked with that package before ;)

Comment: @BigDataScientist Thanks. Done :)